# use button close on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I trying to use close modal button in modal but is not working.

My code:

```
<center><button class="bleu b_modal">Modal test</button></center>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".b_modal").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.open({content: '\
            <center><button class="b_close">Close modal</button></center>\
        '});
    });

    $('.b_close').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        modal.close();
    });

    var modal = (function(){
        var
        method = {},
        $modal,
        $content,
        $close;

        method.open = function(settings) {
            $content.empty().append(settings.content);
            $modal.show();
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        };

        method.close = function() {
            $modal.hide();
            $content.empty();
            document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
        };

        $modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
        $content = $('<div id="modal_content"></div>');
        $close = $('\
            <center><button class="b_close">Close modal</button></center>\
        ');

        $modal.hide();
        $modal.append($content, $close);

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').append($modal);
        });

        $close.click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            method.close();
        });

        return method;
    }());

</script>
```

The close button on modal not working but the second close button out modal is working. The problem is in my `$('.b_close').click`, but nothing that I tried works.

```
modal.open({content: '\
            <center><button class="b_close">Close modal</button></center>\
        '});
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines seems to be your problem:

```
modal.open({content: '\<center><button class="b_close">Close modal</button></center>\'});
$close = $('\<center><button class="b_close">Close modal</button></center>\');
```

Remove the center tags, they're not supported in HTML5. Also, remove the backslashes ( \ ). The one at the end is actually escaping the ' that would otherwise terminate your string.

```
$close = $('<button class="b_close">Close modal</button>');
```

And I suggest not passing the button into the .open() method. Just call it:

```
modal.open();
```

And then use the var $close in your function.

```
var  $close = $('<button class="b_close">Close modal</button>');

    method.open = function() {
        $content.append($close);
        $modal.show();
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    };
```

Finally, you don't need to call .empty() on your content in your .open() and .close() methods.

I've made some edits to your code, here's a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nxv597a/2/

Comment: the center balise is just for test on my page, but don't solve my problem.

Comment: Take a look at the jsfiddle i've made for you. it shows a working solution

Comment: @SankarRaj fixed it

Comment: How to add text and close button on the modal ?

Comment: That's probably grounds for a new question. I've helped you solve the close button issue here, but you could still pass settings into your .open() method, there's just no need to pass the close button.

Comment: ok. Thx for your help. But my old code work external close button, not really the solution...

Comment: you're welcome. if my answer was helpful in solving your issue, please remember to upvote and accept it for people with issues similar to this in the future.